# Bash test with no options appears to work, but why?

Tags: bash

I want to pass options to my bash script. If the option "GUI" is set, zenity should be used for input and output instead of the console. Currently I'm passing the option as an environment variable like this:

```
GUI=1 ./my_bash_script.sh
```

Then I found out that I could test for the length of the variable like this:

```
if [ -n "$GUI" ]; then
```

But then, quite randomly, I discovered that just testing the string with no options also appears to work as expected:

```
if [ "$GUI" ]; then
```

I've read the manual entry for `test` but I can't see any explanation for what happens if you just pass a string without any arguments. I'm guessing that if it receives an empty string it returns true, and otherwise it returns false? Is that the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct.  From the [`test(1)` man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?test):

> ```
> -n STRING
>       the length of STRING is nonzero
>
> STRING equivalent to -n STRING
> ```